# Is the exponential function isometrical?

Tags: lie-groups

I'm reading Stillwell's Naive Lie Theory. At end of Ch4 he said,

> For readers acquainted with differential geometry, it should be
> mentioned that the exponential function can be generalized even beyond
> matrix groups, to Riemannian manifolds. In this setting, the
> exponential function maps the tangent space $T_P (M)$ at point $P$ on
> a Riemannian manifold $M$ into $M$ by mapping lines through $O$ in
> $T_P (M)$ isometrically onto geodesics of $M$ through $P$. The
> Riemannian manifolds $\mathbb S^1 = \{z \in \mathbb C : |z| = 1\}$ and
> $\mathbb S^3 = \{q \in \mathbb H : |q| = 1\}$, and their tangent spaces
> $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^3$ , nicely illustrate the geodesic aspect
> of exponentiation. The exponential map sends straight lines through
> $O$ in the tangent space isometrically to geodesic circles in the
> manifolds (to $\mathbb S^1$ itself in $\mathbb C$, and to the unit
> circles $\cos \theta + u \sin \theta$ in $\mathbb H$, which are
> geodesic because they are the largest possible circles in
> $\mathbb S^3$ ).

I'm not familia with differential geometry at all, so probably should not ask here... But I just can't help wondering, how could the exponential function be isometrical?

For example, function $e^z$ maps the straight line $i\theta$ into $e^{i\theta}$, i.e. the unit circle $\mathbb S^1$. But the straight line has infinite length, while $\mathbb S^1$'s circumference is only $2\pi$, how could $e^z$ be an isometry? by isometrical it means the map shall keep the distance?

Comment: The equal lengths are the path lengths. So this really means that $\left|\frac{d}{d\theta}e^{i\theta}\right|=1.$ Or, locally it is an isometry. Given any $\theta,$ there is a neighborhood of $\theta$ on which $e^{ix}$ is an isometry.

Comment: To supplement Thomas's comment, the exponential mapping is only "isometrical" along radial rays in the tangent space, not transversely to these rays.

Comment: thanks both. guess that's differential geometry default practice that i'm unaware of..